# code to copy rows of found value only to another workbook sheet

Tags: vba

I got this code online for copying the row where value is found and pasting it to  sheet of another wb modified to my need. 2 things even after modification does not work for my changes-

1. I need to copy only those rows that match the request for instance my data is in row 11. but the code in variable 'last copy row' pastes all the used rows after 11.
2. I have modified the original codes to suit my requirements of 2 workbooks. but I get an run time error on the copy code:

   `src.Range(Cells(matchRow, 1), Cells(lastCopyRow, lastCol)).Copy _
       tgt.Range("A" & lastPasteRow)`

could somebody guide me as to what is going wrong?

```
Sub CopyRowAndBelowToTarget()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 as workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim match As Range

    Set wb1= workbooks(srcwb)
    Set wb2 = workbooks (tgtwb)
    Set src = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = wb2.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lastCopyRow As Long
    Dim lastPasteRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim matchRow As Long
    Dim findMe As String

    ' specify what we're searching for
    findMe = "s"

    ' find our search string in column A (1)
    Set match = src.Columns(1).Find(What:=findMe, After:=src.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ' figure out what row our search string is on
    matchRow = match.Row

    ' get the last row and column with data so we know how much to copy
    lastCopyRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = src.Cells(1, src.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' find out where on our target sheet we should paste the results
    lastPasteRow = tgt.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' use copy/paste syntax that doesn't use the clipboard 
    ' and doesn't select or activate
    src.Range(Cells(matchRow, 1), Cells(lastCopyRow, lastCol)).Copy _
        tgt.Range("A" & lastPasteRow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
src.Range(src.Cells(matchRow, 1), src.Cells(lastCopyRow, lastCol)).Copy _
        Destination:=tgt.Cells(lastPasteRow + 1, 1)
```